# utf-8 character in different font

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

So basically I have a  that says Paieška and š, the utf 8 character is in different font:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<h2 class="section-title">Paieška</h2>

.section-title, .section-highlight {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Use a font that supports all relevant characters. [Font substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution) from a different font can used if the chosen font is missing that character. It may be ugly, but it's still better than rendering a box.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of [font substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution).

When the chosen font is lacking a character, unicode renderers can use the same character from a substitution font instead. The alternative would be to render a placeholder like `�`. Better ugly than unreadable.

To avoid this problem, use a font that supports all the characters you use. If you really want this font, you can specify fallback fonts which are as similar as possible to the original font, while containing more characters. Remember, css lets you specify a list of fonts, which should be tried in order by the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the š by &#x0161;

As in:
Paie&#x0161;ka

Check also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this won't help. It's displaying the right character after all.